# Считывание нескольких строк из input()

Tags: python

Всех приветствую. Возникла такая проблема:

Если в `input()` брать 1 строку, типа:

```
x = input()

print(x)
```

И ввести:

```
Привет, как дела?
```

`print()` выведет

> ```
> Привет, как дела?
> ```

Но если ввести такую(е):

```
Привет

как

дела

?
```

он выведет лишь

> Привет

Как можно объединить все эти строки в 1?

Comment: как по-вашему, скрипт должен понимать, что пользователь закончил ввод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `input()` ждёт, пока пользователь нажнёт на клавиш <kbd>Enter</kbd>, и затем немедленно возвратит введенную строку, также когда пользователь затем что-то писал, это или потеряется, или передается последующей команде на ввод с клавиатуры.

Значит, нельзя 1 командой `input()` ввести более строк - нужно это повторить, например в таком цикле:

```
text = ""

while True:
    x = input()
    if x:
        text += x + " "
    else:
        break

print(text)
```

Для ввода

```
Привет
как
дела
?
```

и ещё одного нажатия на <kbd>Enter</kbd> получится вывод

> ```
> Привет как дела ?
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = (input())
number = []
while True:
    try:
        number.append(a)
        a = int (input())
    except:
        break
print(number)
```

Можно так попробовать, но надо нажать после ввода еще раз энтер и будут кавычки квадратные со скобками.

Comment: Ваш скрипт вылетит в цикле сразу же, если пользователь введет что-нибудь кроме числа.

Comment: То есть? Так я его проверил на "Привет, как дела?", я так понимаю, цель - сделать в строчку, вроде работает. К сожалению, не знаю ничего лучше, чтобы сделать тоже самое эффективнее

Comment: Нет. не работает ваш скрипт. Я не знаю, как вы его проверяли, но при вводе второй строки (которая циклом обрабатывается), он у вас вылетит. потому что пытается конвертировать ее в целое число.

Comment: А, да, int там лишний. Странно, что оно тогда работает у меня.